# Not able to view the Datahub Config in Pimcore

Tags: pimcore, pimcore-datahub

I am newbie in Pimcore and i am trying to install pimcore and datahub for my usercases to exlore

1. I have installed Pimcore using below link which is successful  [Docker Based Installlation](https://pimcore.com/docs/platform/Pimcore/Getting_Started/Installation/Docker_Based_Installation)
2. I am trying to install datahub in current instance pimcore using this document [Datahub Installation](https://pimcore.com/docs/platform/Datahub/Installation_and_Upgrade/)
3. I can see the pimcoredatahub and admin ui bundles are installed but i cannot able to see the datahub config option when i login using admin access

[image]

[image]

Can you gguys help what i am missing here to configure datahub and in the above document ,noticed user must have admin access and plugin_datahub_config permission. How can i check these permission having or not ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Datahub with the "Network"-Icon above the search Icon on the left sidebar. There you can create Datahub endpoints and make configurations inside.

To create Configurations, there is a button like Add Configuration in the Datahub View